# How can I program a button in HTML to go to a link?

Tags: html

I have the following in my Razor view:

```
<button class="float-left submit-button" title="Test Questions">Test</button>
```

How can I make it so that when the button is clicked it goes to the following URL ?

```
"~/F000C/Home-About"
```

Comment: Why don't you use a link?

Comment: Well because my template is all set up to use button.

Comment: What prevents you from changing the template?

Comment: @Melina: why is your template all set up to use `<button>` when you want something that will go to a URL when clicked on? HTML’s element for that functionality is `<a>`, and has been since the first version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="float-left submit-button" title="Test Questions" onclick="javascript:window.open('~/F000C/Home-About')">Test</button>
```

if you really want button element, then you should insert `onclick` event.

or:

```
<button class="float-left submit-button" title="Test Questions" onclick="window.location.assign('~/F000C/Home-About')">Test</button>
```

Comment: Will this replace the current window or open a new one? What I want to do is have it replace the current.

Comment: No, it will open the link in a new window. Use `window.location =url` instead if you want to open it in current window. The `javascript:` pseudoprotocol is by the way totally unnecessary.

Comment: Hi BalusC - Can you post your window.location as an answer or add as an alternative to yours. Thanks

Comment: @Melina: I won't post solutions which don't work in all browsers.

Comment: @BalusC - What do mean? Our site uses a lot of javascript already.

Comment: @doniyor - Thanks very much. By the way. What is the difference between .assign and =url ?

Comment: The onclick doesn't degrade gracefully. So if JS is disabled, the button won't work at all.

Comment: @BalusC, if js is disabled, many things wont work, so i strongly assume, js will work. 
 - Melina: after ``window.location=url``, you cannot go back, the session will be dead..

Comment: Doniyor, poorly designed websites will indeed break. Properly designed websites degrade gracefully while still keeping the core functionality (in other words, JS is only been used for progressive enhancement, e.g. ajax, looknfeel, etc).

Comment: you are right, what would you suggest in this case, instead of ``onclick`` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a link *and* a button, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><button class="float-left submit-button" title="Test Questions">Test</button></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple form that contains just a button:

```
<form action="~/F000C/Home-About">
<button class="float-left submit-button" title="Test Questions">Test</button>
</form>
```

You may need to set `form { display: inline }`, because a form is displayed as a block by default.

It is however a much better idea to use a normal link element and style it like a button (easy in CSS these days). Think about search engines. (They usually don’t submit forms, and they should not be expected to run JavaScript; but they just love links.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use CSS and HTML to make a link look like an awesome button. More examples [here](http://www.zurb.com/blog_uploads/0000/0617/buttons-03.html).

**HTML**

```
<a class="awesome" href="http://www.example.com">Super Awesome Button Link &raquo;</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.awesome, .awesome:visited {
    background: #666; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 5px 10px 6px; 
    color: #fff; 
  font:12px Calibri, Verdana;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.awesome:hover { background-color: #111; color: #fff; }
```